# WSL2 doesn't see installed Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I installed Ubuntu by using WSL-2 on my windows 10 machine. Everything seemed ok. I use VS Code on Windows for editing/saving files on WSL. I continue to write code this way for about 1 mount. Just few days ago, VS Code gave me a warning that it cannot communicate with linux via ssh.  I checked `wsl --list` command on powershell in order to see if everything is ok. But it turns out that it does not return anything !

I checked if the virtual machine image still exists, and it seems that the `.vhdx` file exists.

I have many source files inside this VM. Could someone help me ?

B.R.